# find command and path parameter

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Having the file structure like that:

> /root/abc/1.txt
>   /root/abc/2.txt

and sitting in `/root` directory.

1.) Why doesn't the command:

> find . -path "abc/*.txt"

returns no results while

> find . -path "./abc/*.txt"

and

> find . -path "*/abc/*.txt"

do works?

2.) What's the difference between `find . -path "./abc/*.txt"`
and `find . -path "*/abc/*.txt"`

Answer (score 2):

Question 1:

The `-path pattern` parameter matches the entire filename.

```
$ find
.
./abc
./abc/1.txt
./abc/2.txt
```

The pattern `abc/*.txt` does not match without the leading `./`.

Question 2:

The wildcard `*` can match any string of any length (including `/` and `.` characters).  The parameter
`-path "*/abc/*.txt"` has two wildcards, so it can match any of the following:

```
./abc/a.txt
*     *


./abc/ANYTHING.txt
*     ********

def/ghi/abc/SOMETHING.txt
*******     *********

./abc/def_dsa/faf.txt
*     ***********
```

Comment: I've made a typo in question 2: should be `find . -path "*/abc/*.txt"` rather then `find . -path "\*/abc/*.txt"`. So can You be so nice and answer such corrected question?

Comment: @Mulligan Edited the answer.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thx. for help:-)

Comment: So Am i right that `-path` pattern is applied to the result of what `find .`produces and that's why my first attempt fails?

Comment: You are correct

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

The following sentence is from the `-path` option in the `find` manual:

> Note that the pattern match test applies to the whole file name,
>   starting from one of the start points named on the command line.

This explains why your alternative search patterns (`"./abc/*.txt"` and `"*/abc/*.txt"`) work. Your original search pattern (`"abc/*.txt"`) will work only if the search root is `abc`:

```
find abc/ -path "abc/*.txt"
```

As for the difference between `"./abc/*.txt"` and `"*/abc/*.txt"`, neither will try to expand the string before calling `find`: the first will find files only in the top-level directory `./abc/`, but the second will find files in *any* subdirectory `abc`, such as `./def/abc/`, `./ghi/def/abc/`, etc, as well as `./abc/`.

Comment: I've made a typo in question 2: should be `find . -path "*/abc/*.txt"` rather then `find . -path "\*/abc/*.txt"`. So can You be so nice and answer such corrected question?

Comment: The difference between `"./abc/*.txt"` and `"*/abc/*.txt"` is that the first will match text files in the top-level `./abc` directory only, while the second will match not only here, but also in `./def/abc` or in any other subdirectory further down the hierarchy.